# Font in h1 different when offline and online

Tags: html, css

Hello I am fairly new to HTML and CSS. I've just began hosting my site and since installing an SSL certificate to it (whether relevant or not) my header's font has reverted to the default font. When I open the html file offline the header is the appropriate 'Damion' font however when I go to domain that is not the case.

The website is eliasmalik.com, the text in question being "Under development"

Below is the index.html and main.css files for the website:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Elias Malik</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <link href="tools/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:600,700|Damion' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="diamond.ico">
</head>

    <body>
        <div class="bc">
            <h1>Under development</h1>
        </div>

                <div id= "footer">
            <div>
                <ul class ="social">
                        <li class="facebook"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/elias.malik.7"></a></li>
                        <li class="instagram"><a href="https://instagram.com/eliasrmalik"></a></li>
                        <li class="linkedin"><a href="https://uk.linkedin.com/in/eliasrmalik"></a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

and

```
 html 
    {
        background: url(devbc.jpg)no-repeat center center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;

    }

    body
    {
        position: fixed;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .bc h1
    {
        font-family: 'Damion', cursive;
        top: 40%;
        left: 49%;
        position:absolute;
        transform: translateX(-40%) translateY(-49%); 
        color: white;
        font-size: 62px;


    }

    #footer{
        width: 105%;

    }


    ul
    {
    list-style-type: none;
    }

    ul.social
    {
    width: 202px;
    margin: 555px auto 0;
    height: 52px;
    }

    ul.social li{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    height: 52px;
    margin-right: 12px;
    }

    ul.social li a{
    display: block;
    width: 52px;
    height: 52px;
    }


    ul.social li.facebook
    {
    background-image: url(facebook.png);
    }

    ul.social li.instagram 
    {
    background-image: url(instagram.png);
    }

    ul.social li.linkedin
    {
    background-image: url(linkedin.png);
    }
```

This is a screenshot of how the page is supposed to display: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxsyg.jpg

And yes the version in my file client is the same as the one offline

Comment: Tried changing `http://fonts.googleapis.com` to `https://fonts.googleapis.com`? Getting any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: better yet, skip the http/https and just use `//fonts.googleapis.com` to request the resource using the same protocol as the page

Comment: This is unrelated, but you should considered saving your background in a lower quality or size. 1.8mb for a background file is a bit much. If  you are using Photoshop, try using the save for web option (ctrl-alt-shift-S)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The font is http: not https:, so it will block it as being insecure.

Using Chrome, I went to your site, opened the dev tools (F12) and reloaded the page. The following error is displayed in the console.

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://eliasmalik.com/' was loaded over
>   HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet
>   'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:600,700|Damion'.
>   This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Change your link to the font from google to https and it should work.

Or, take the very sound advice (that I am remiss in forgetting) from hair raisin below:

> better yet, skip the http/https and just use //fonts.googleapis.com to request the resource using the same protocol as the page

Comment: better yet, skip the http/https and just use `//fonts.googleapis.com` to request the resource using the same protocol as the page

Answer (score 1):

Change

`<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:600,700|Damion' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`

to remove the http protocol so that it reads: **//fonts.googleapis.com**

`<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:600,700|Damion' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`

Removing the protocol allows your files to request http when needed and automatically changes to https when secure files are needed.

Because you have a SSL you need to have all your references be secure.  It was blocking non secure sources (your font) because you specified the font to be served over http and not https.

Comment: better yet, skip the http/https and just use `//fonts.googleapis.com` to request the resource using the same protocol as the page

Comment: That's what it's doing.  However, the trend of using no protocol is starting to become an anti-pattern now and permanently using https when available is making its way back into best practices.

Comment: yep, you're right. I don't know how I misread that. your answer gets my upvote

Answer (score 0):

You might try changing this line:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:600,700|Damion' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

To:

```
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:600,700|Damion' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

I suspect that your browser might be blocking the loading of that style because your page is https (secure), but you're requesting the CSS from an insecure source (http).

By leaving the http: off, you'll allow your page to request the CSS securely when your page is secure, and use plain http if the page uses http.

Answer (score 0):

Your web browser is blocking the loading of mixed content - loading http resources on an https site.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/MixedContent

an easy way to fix it is to change

`http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:600,700|Damion`

to

`https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:600,700|Damion`

Comment: better yet, skip the http/https and just use `//fonts.googleapis.com` to request the resource using the same protocol as the page

Answer (score 0):

You can download the font and use css to "set" it, you'll be able to use it as a normal font after that.

```
@font-face {
font-family: yourfontname;
src: url(Yourfonturl.woff2);
}
```

And then to use it :

```
#yourid {font-family: yourfontname}
```